# System tray icon for Nextloud

Tags: pantheon

I've installed the Nextcloud Client through with a Snap. There is no system tray icon showing up. Is there a way to get it or is it an issue of Nextcloud?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to manually add the icon in the application drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "problem" is that the Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana is no longer in elementary juno. if you want to install it, try the following link:

[Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://translate.google.cl/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es-419&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fentornosgnulinux.com%2F2018%2F08%2F15%2Fcomo-instalar-wingpanel-indicator-ayatana-en-elementary-os-juno%2F&edit-text=)

resume:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary

sudo apt update

sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

change OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME; to OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;

Ctrl + O (save change) Ctrl + X (close)

reboot

It worked for me.

Cya.

Comment: Thanks that worked out.

Comment: nice dude! enjoy eOS ;)