# Zoom app not closing correctly

Tags: release-hera

i installed zoom app via Eddy and it's working normally, but if i close it, the process actually stay in running state, so next time i am trying to launch zoom it's said that it's already running and i have to use killall zoom first, and then it's starts normaly.

***Update:***
the problem that on closing, it's stays in system tray, but without an icon, here is a workaround to enable system tray icons
[System tray icon for Nextloud](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/system-tray-icon-for-nextloud)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can configure Zoom to quit the application when closed. That's my default mode.

Open Zoom configuration (cog icon on the main window) and Under *General > Application* check *When closed, quit the application directly"*.

With this configuration, Zoom will close whenever you want to be closed. Otherwise, just minimize and keep it running (and accesible via Plank panel).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more detail?

I think your problem here is that Zoom continues to run inside of a tray process so you’ve just go to check your taskbar and see if Zoom is still running on there. If so, click on it and the current running Zoom instance will show itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Exit" menu item in Zoom that prevents the app from continuing to run in the background when you close the window:

[image]

Comment: yes, that way it worked, but it's not very convenient to exit that way. I just noticed that in Ubuntu 18.04 if i click cross it's still running and i can see an icon in tray, but in elementary where is no tray, just dock bar.

Comment: it sounds intentional on the developer's part - have you contacted them about it yet?

Comment: oh I'm just seeing the answer that reveals the option in settings above.  you may wish to rephrase your question as Zoom is closing ”correctly" as designed :)